# How can i prove that this integral is convergent/divergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

This is my equation:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dx}{x\sin2x}$$

I wish to prove that it's convergent or divergent, by $P$ test and/or comparison test, but it does not seem to be applicable...

Is it correct, that $1/x$ is smaller or equal to $\frac {1}{x\sin2x}$?

That would mean, $\frac 1x$ is divergent by $p$ test... since it's divergent by $p$ test, and $\frac {1}{x\sin2x}$ is bigger, $\frac {1}{x\sin2x}$ is divergent as well.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is integral is divergent, because at $x=0$ you have $\frac{1}{x\sin2x}\sim \frac{1}{2x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Over the interval $I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $0<\sin x<x$, hence for any $\varepsilon\in I$:
$$\int_{\varepsilon}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{x\sin(2x)}\geq\int_{\varepsilon}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}-\frac{2}{\pi}$$
and your integral is clearly divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\sin\left(2x\right)\leq 2x
 $$ in all real range $\left(0,\infty\right)
 $, then $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{x\sin\left(2x\right)}\geq\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{2x^{2}}dx=\infty.
 $$

Answer (score -2):

You can bring it to $\int \frac{dx}{x\sin x}$ integral with some replacements which doesn't converge.

Comment: What you said is correct, but might not be helpful. If the OP knows how to solve your integral, probably he can also solve his.